# How to access the values in an array and put them in html table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I just want to put the data into the second column. Everyone have source code for this?[I want to put comma separated values into html table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22VVS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to output the whole content of an array, without having to specify the array's keys

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Your stylesheet here -->
</head>

<body>

<h2>My cool table</h2>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Items</th>
  <th>Stocks</th>
<tr>

<?php

// Create the array
$myArray=array('TV' => '1', 'Speaker' => '34', 'Radio' => '11');

// Output all of the items in the table
foreach($myArray as $item => $stock){
echo "<tr><td>{$item}</td><td>{$stock}</td></tr>";
}

?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The output should resemble the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Your stylesheet here -->
</head>

<body>

<h2>My cool table</h2>

<table>
<tr>
  <th>Items</th>
  <th>Stocks</th>
<tr>

<tr><td>TV</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Speaker</td><td>34</td></tr><tr><td>Radio</td><td>11</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>


<?php 
$key = array(1,2,3);
?>

<table >
  <thead>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td><?php echo $key[0]?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td><?php echo $key[1]?></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

To access array, use $variable_name[position].